# Do Gaussian binomial coefficients work on vector spaces of the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$?

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces, binomial-coefficients, finite-fields

It's known that the [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}{k}_p$ counts $k$-dimensional subspaces of the vector space $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ ($p \in \mathbb{P}$). However, if we use another field, say $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ ($m \ge 2$), the coefficients don't work anymore.

For instance, when $n = 2$, we have that the actual number of subspaces of the vector space $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}^2$ is $$C_{p^m} = \dfrac{p^{m+2}+p^{m+1}-(2m+3)p+2m+1}{(p-1)^2}$$ (Ref: [oeis](http://oeis.org/A060724)). On the other hand, the coefficients give us another answer: $$G_{p^m} = \sum_{k=0}^2 \binom{2}{k}_{p^m} = p^m+3$$. When $m = 1$, two answers actually collide.

**My questions** are that why the coefficients don't work and how we can fix the counting process so that they work again.

I've googled quite a lot, and it seems that the coefficients do work. However, my "counter"-example has yet explained.

Comment: The coefficients do work. In particular, ${n \choose k}_q$ is the number of subspaces of dimension $k$ of the vector space $F_q^n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient

Comment: @ASKASK I've made some edits. Please elaborate my "counter"-example.

Comment: I don't understand what your oeis reference is supposed to be showing. Subspaces of a vector space are not the same thing as subgroups of a product of cyclic groups

Comment: The OEIS sequence does not count subspaces in a vector space over a field of order $p^n$ but submodules in a free module over the ring $Z/p^n$, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: In particular, the additive group of $F_{p^m}$ is *not* $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$ whenever $m \geq 2$, so the additive group of $F_{p^m}^2$ is not $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$, which is I think what you're going off of.

Comment: @All: I know they're different things in general. What I mean is that to me, they seem to be the same in these particular cases. That's my concern. Sorry for not making it clear enough. Also, thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: But they are not the same! That is precisely why the two things you mention in your question are different!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I realized that and made some edits to my previous comment. Sorry again.

Comment: But your revised question makes the same confusion as before. If $n>1$, the ring $Z/p^nZ$ is not a field, so that the gaussian polynomials don't count anything related to them. You are simply misinterpreting the OEIS sequence.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez There is no revised question. That's all my mistakes. Sorry again. And thank you all.

Comment: There is no reason to be sorry for!